# How can I force a line break in rmarkdown's title for beamer output?

Tags: r, yaml, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I have a quite long title in a rmarkdown document and I would like to force a line break in a specific position.

Minimum example:

```
---
title: "Quite long title want the * line break at the asterisk"
output: beamer_presentation
---
```

I have tried: \n, \newline, \ and a manual line break. None of them seem to work.

I believe it has to be quite straightforward but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to escape the `\`:

```
---
title: "Quite long title want the \\newline line break at the asterisk"
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    keep_tex: true
---
test
```

[image]

Comment: For me, this results in " \newline" showing up in the title

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor Are your rmarkdown, pandoc etc up-to-date?

Comment: Unrelated...but do you know how to force justify text in bullet points in beamer rmarkdown?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387885/36296 (use at your own risk :) )